# Customize zsh prompt for normal/superuser?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

How can I make zsh shell use "$ and #" for "normal and superuser" instead of "% and #"?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to `~/.zshrc` did the trick for me:

```
PROMPT='%(!.#.$) '
```

It puts `#` for root, and `$` for others.

Answer (score 0):

The currently deleted self-answer is correct, so far as it goes. In a prompt,  `%(!.#.$)` will expand to `#` if the effective user ID of the shell is 0, `$` otherwise.

However, be aware that if your current prompt is something like `PS1='%(!.#.$) '`, simply starting a privileged shell may not preserve the current value of `PS1`, even if exported. For example, on macOS, the default `/etc/zshrc` file explicitly sets the value of `PS1`, discarding any value you may have expected to be "inherited".

That said, I'd recommend against using `$` in the prompt, as it is heavily associated with Bourne-shell descendants that don't deviate quite so much from standard interactive behavior. `zsh` provides a *large* number of features designed explicitly for (and conflicting with standard) interactive use, so a `%` prompt provides a good reminder of that.

Answer (score 0):

Check **`EUID`** (effective user id) in **`~/.zshrc`**:

```
if [[ $EUID == 0 ]]; then
    PROMPT='# '
else
    PROMPT='$ '
fi
```

Comment: The only difference between this and the existing conditional prompt escape is that you check the real user id rather than the effective user id.

Comment: This won't change the prompt if the EUID changes while the session is active.

Comment: Well, then check `$EUID` then. Anyway I am using the same `~/.zshrc` for both `root` and normal user. So I just write that that way.

Comment: @chepner, in my `~/.zshrc` it changes some color as well (red for `root`); so I really have to check the `UID` using `if ... then ... else`. Merely `PS1='%(!.#.$) '` is not enough for me. So I think it may be `if ... then ...` is what sramji wants. By the way I do not know how a `zsh` session can change the `EUID` while running.

Comment: If you start as root, you can drop privileges by assigning directly to `EUID`.

Comment: @chepner, Yes! Indeed! I did not know that the "command" `EUID=1000` change the effective uid right in the script. Thanks. I updated to EUID.